# Show replies to individual comments in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm building a comment system and I want to show the replies to comments made.

```
Models:
class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)

class Reply(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```

The thing is that I don't really know how to send the replies related to the individual comment to the template. Currently, my view is:

```
Views
def view_thread(request, thread_slug):
    thread = Thread.objects.get(slug=thread_slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(thread = thread)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ResponderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment()
            comment.body = form.cleaned_data['body']
            comment.thread = thread
            comment.save()
            new_form = ResponderForm()
            reply_form = ReplyForm()
            return render(request, 'view_thread.html', {
                                      'Thread': thread,
                                      'form': new_form,
                                      'replyform': reply_form,
                                      'Comments': comments.order_by('-created'),
            })
    else:
        form = ResponderForm()
        thread = Thread.objects.get(slug=thread_slug)
        reply_form = ReplyForm()
        return render(request, 'view_thread.html', {
                                  'Thread': thread,
                                  'form': form,
                                  'replyform': reply_form,
                                  'Comments': comments.order_by('-created'),
        })
```

It's working fine, I can see the thread and it's comments. But how should I proceed to be able to do something as below to also show the replies to each comment?

```
{% for Comment in comments %}
 {{ Comment.body }}
 {%for Reply in replies %}
  {{Reply.body }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried some horribles workarounds, which didn't work. I know there are some packages that does this but since I'm still learning as I go, I think it's better for me to do it myself. Also, I realize this question has been asked before, but the replies didn't clarify my problem.

It seems I'm missing something basic here. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Backward" relationships are [described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
{% for Reply in Comment.reply_set.all %}
    {{ Reply.body }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow...I feel so stupid. I was trying that without realizing I was inside the loop, so I was using "... in Comments.reply_set.all" instead of Comment.reply_set.all. Thank you!